# Flex datagrid different fonts for column header and the text in the corresponding cell

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, fonts

```
For a flex datagrid : 

How do I have different fonts for a column header
and the text in the corresponding cells?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is one workaround : 


<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="colHeader" dataField="marHD" width="100" editable="false" fontFamily="Arial" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="text">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                   <mx:Text fontFamily="myfontfamily"/>
            </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```